# Bootstrap toast alert: bootstrap not defined

Tags: javascript, toast

I'm using Bootstrap 5.3 right out of the box to create a toast message. The console says that within this code:

```
const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('buynow')
const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')

if (true) {
  const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample)
  toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toastBootstrap.show()
  });
};
```

that bootstrap is not defined. I'm stumped. I don't know of anything I can tweak to fix this error.

```
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b20ad3118a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The if (true) is just something I used to test the if statement. It should say: if (toastTrigger).

Comment: How are you loading the Bootstrap JS? Are you executing this script before or after it's loaded?

Answer (score 2):

This code has no issues if you import the library correctly.

```js
const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('buynow')
const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')

if (true) {
  const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample)
  toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toastBootstrap.show()
  });
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buynow">Buy Now</button>

  <div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
        <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        Hello, world! This is a toast message.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b20ad3118a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I suggest checking if the library success imported in `Inspect Element > Network > JS` and ensuring all status is `200`. Make sure your internet/proxy doesn't block the library.

[image]

---

I have checked your [codes](https://github.com/treycoggins/web210/tree/woozle/week7). There are a few problem can be solved:

1. Move your `app.js` to the bottom of `body` because the browser loads components in ascending order from top to down, so `.getElementById` will be `null` if `<script>` at the top position of the targeted id.

```html
...
  </footer>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

2. Delete all `.stretched-link` classes from `Buy Now` button because this class blocking the click event of this button.

```html
...
<a role="button"
   class="buy-now btn btn-outline-danger text-decoration-none fs-3 fw-bold px-4 py-2 rounded-5">
   Buy Now
</a>
...
```

3. Change the implementation of toast calling like this:

```js
const toastTriggers=document.getElementsByClassName('buy-now');
const toastLiveExample=document.getElementById('liveToast');

[...toastTriggers].forEach((toastTrigger) => {
  if (toastTrigger) {
    const toastBootstrap=bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample);
    toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toastBootstrap.show()
    });
  };
})
```

4. Remove this button element because it is no longer needed.

```html
<button id="buynow">Click</button>
```

5. Add `width: 30%` at the logo of the toast to prevent a bigger size of it.

```html
...
<img src="img/logo.png" class="rounded me-2" alt="Roots Reggae Music logo" style="width: 30%;">
...
```

---

Continuation:

> 1.) Scroll spy is acting weird. It's putting the active class on the 1st and 4th li, seemingly at random

To fix this, you need to put `div.data-bs-target` on `<main>` tag and close that tag on `<footer>` tag.

```html
...
<!-- Main Content section -->
<div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">
  <main class="main" id="main-content">
  ...
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Footer section -->
<footer class="container-fluid">
...
```

> 2.) Tooltips are not showing at all

Simple, you can import [popper.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js) library before `bootstrap.min.js`

```html
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
```

That's it.

Comment: Yeah I started to think something was wrong with the library because a couple other components didn't work when I added them. But only the font awesome library failed. This hasn't affected my custom scripts. Would it affect the bootstrap library? I'll try commenting out the font awesome script.

Comment: I added the bootstrap.js file directly to my directories and it didn't help. A modal component on the same page does work.

Comment: Now I'm really at a loss. I added the bootstrap library directly and commented out the cdn, and now half of my markup is styled, but half of it isn't. Some bootstrap is applied, but not all. Also, I can see the tooltip showing up, but of course the javascript is not there. Other components are not show, such as the toast and the modal. I assume because they have to be toggled on.

Comment: <link href="bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <script src="bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Oops, I did have my .css file commented out as well....However, still having the issue with the scrollspy. Other components, like my modals and accordions are working, and the .active class I can see is being applied, but only to the first link and is not changing dynamically, although it will randomly be applied to the third link on some refreshes. The hrefs match the ids. The toast is not working at all.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: I uploaded my codebase to Github.
https://github.com/treycoggins/web210/tree/woozle/week7

Comment: Ok, I will check it later

Comment: Thanks, Jordy. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: OMG man you are a wizard! I can't thank you enough. I learned something about the spread operator and the forEach method. I'm going to refactor my for loops now. I would have never thought about the stretch-link class. I don't know enough about BS to dig under the hood. How did you track down the conflict with the click event?

Comment: I don't want to ask too much of you. But perhaps, if you have time, you can look into two issues with that website. 1.) Scroll spy is acting weird. It's putting the active class on the 1st and 4th li, seemingly at random. So I know the script is working, but something is messing it up. 2.) Tooltips are not showing at all.

Comment: I'm getting the following error in the tooltips.js file:

createPopper is not a function
    at je._createPopper (tooltip.js:375:19)
    at je.show (tooltip.js:214:25)
    at tooltip.js:509:14

Where the tooltip.js file throws an error here. Odd because I'm accessing an element that I know is a popoverList node list.

_createPopper(tip) {
    const placement = execute(this._config.placement, [this, tip, this._element])
    const attachment = AttachmentMap[placement.toUpperCase()]
    return Popper.createPopper(this._element, tip, this._getPopperConfig(attachment))
  }

Comment: @surfturkey I have fixed those problems. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I closed the footer and wrapped main in a div with the attributes you mentioned. The active class shows up on the first li and is removed when the scroll reaches the next anchor, but it's not adding the active class to the following achors still. I did remove the scroll spy attributes from the body tag. Was I not supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes you must remove it from body tag, then only that div that contains `data-bs`

Comment: I did remove them. It's better, it's removing the active class when its supposed to.  But it's not adding it to the next li.

Comment: I suggest to create new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you import 'bootstrap' into your component?

9 times out of 10 when there is an undefined error it's because something wasn't properly imported (or required) in a component or script.

Comment: I have the script at the end of my HTML. I'm using the CDN.

Comment: Check to see if your script is loaded before or after the bootstrap scripts. It needs to be executed after the Bootstrap scripts. Are there any async/defer attributes with the CDN scripts?

Comment: My script loads after the BS scripts. There are no async or defer attributes.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your html header or footer (wherever your other scripts are)? It'll be helpful to everyone trying to help you out.

Comment: I edited the post. I just have one script loading following the bootstrap.js