# Bootstrap Tooltips and PopOvers throwing error on createPopper()

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to setup Bootstrap popovers and I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
s.createPopper is not a function
    at je._createPopper (tooltip.js:375:19)
    at je.show (tooltip.js:214:25)
    at tooltip.js:509:14
```

I have initialized the popovers per the docs with:

```
// Initialize Popovers
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl));
```

The components are attached to buttons:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="display-3 mt-5 m-5 fw-lighter text-uppercase">sponsors</div>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4 align-items-center justify-content-evenly">
      <div id="happy-ifood" class="col sponsor__img rounded-3 border border-info my-3 p-3">
        <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/food-sponsor.png" alt="Happy Food: food sponsor">
        <button class="btn btn-info learn-more text-capitalize text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Happy iFood" data-bs-content="Happy iFood trucks will be on-site with 8 different cuisine options.">learn more</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

The styling for the surrounding elements are:

```
.sponsor__img {
  display: block;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 20rem;
  position: relative;
  /* margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem; */
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.learn-more {
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The error is occurring at the return value of the `_createPopper(tip)` function in the tooltip.js file.

```
_createPopper(tip) {
    const placement = execute(this._config.placement, [this, tip, this._element])
    const attachment = AttachmentMap[placement.toUpperCase()]
    return Popper.createPopper(this._element, tip, this._getPopperConfig(attachment))
  }
```

-from tooltip.js

I would like some direction on what's happening here. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more code and background information. Make sure the imports are correct.

Comment: Did you `<script src>` popper.js and jquery before the bootstrap script link?

Comment: I thought it was included in bootstrap.js. I misread the documentation. I'll check on that.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the docs lol thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Linked comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76025326/bootstrap-toast-alert-bootstrap-not-defined/76028165#comment134109586_76028165